# Binding: Property not found on ViewModel

Tags: maui

I create a simple project "TestBinding". I have "MauiPage1" in "View" folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="TestBinding.View.MauiPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBinding.View"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:TestBinding.ViewModel"
    x:DataType="viewmodel:BaseViewModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding name}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding length}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80"></Entry>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
using TestBinding.ViewModel;
namespace TestBinding.View
{
    public partial class MauiPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        public MauiPage1()
        {
            BaseViewModel baseViewModel = new BaseViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = baseViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

I have "BaseViewModel" in "ViewModel" folder:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestBinding.ViewModel
{
    public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string name = "Tool 1";
        [ObservableProperty]
        public double length;
    }
}
```

In MauiPage1 I get the following errors:
XFC0045 Binding: Property "name" not found on "TestBinding.ViewModel.BaseViewModel".
XFC0045 Binding: Property "length" not found on "TestBinding.ViewModel.BaseViewModel".

If I remove the x:DataType="viewmodel:BaseViewModel" i can build the the project but I get the following warnings:

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'name' property not found on 'TestBinding.ViewModel.BaseViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'length' property not found on 'TestBinding.ViewModel.BaseViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty)

> The name of the generated property will be created based on the field
> name. The generator assumes the field is named either lowerCamel,
> _lowerCamel or m_lowerCamel, and it will transform that to be UpperCamel to follow proper .NET naming conventions. The resulting
> property will always have public accessors, but the field can be
> declared with any visibility (private is recommended).

so when you do this

```
[ObservableProperty]
public string name = "Tool 1";
```

it creates a property named `Name`.  Your binding expression is using `name`, which is the `private field`, not the `public property`